# Why is Lambda suddenly throwing the "Request has expired" error?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

My Lambda function creates EC2 servers via the `create_instances` module of boto3.

I have been triggering this Lambda since morning, and it was creating instances well and good. But suddenly, I keep getting this weird error:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/processing.py",
      54,
      "lambda_handler",
      "KeyName=keyname, SubnetId='subnet-<>', SecurityGroupIds=['sg-<>'])"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py",
      520,
      "do_action",
      "response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py",
      83,
      "__call__",
      "response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/botocore/client.py",
      251,
      "_api_call",
      "return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/botocore/client.py",
      537,
      "_make_api_call",
      "raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (RequestExpired) when calling the RunInstances operation: Request has expired."
}
```

**What has happened?** Pretty sure it was not the code mistake, as the same code well was running since morning.

Comment: Try manually launching that same number of instances, same size and region and see what happens. Look at the limits, perhaps you reached one, or if your Lambda runs in the VPC it could be any of part of the VPC network stack.

Comment: after google i have find out this type of error is coming in some scenarios: 1) The request reached the service more than 15 minutes after the date stamp on the request or more than 15 minutes after the request expiration date (such as for pre-signed URLs), or the date stamp on the request is more than 15 minutes in the future.                                          
2) If you're using temporary security credentials, this error can also occur if the credentials have expired.

Comment: @Raf Ran the exact code from outside of Lambda. It has created an instance.  But, Lambda still throwing this error.

Comment: @Anup The temp. credentials have one hour of visibility, right?  And my code doesn't take more than 3 mins for running.  How come the creds. are expiring?  Sounds very confusing :/

Comment: execution time limit of lambda is 5 minutes , so that might be the issue . also , when you launch instance, you request might wait because of the non availabilty of the required machines architecture . also, invoking lambda is sync or async operation , can oyu share your code snippet ? how many instances you were launching ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was *probably* the 15 minutes delay which Anup was talking about in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562854/why-is-lambda-suddenly-throwing-the-request-has-expired-error#comment76115700_44562854).

I solved it by re-uploading the deployment package and re-tested it. It worked! Quite a weird hack though.

[Would be more than happy to accept an answer which can explain the reason behind this weird behaviour of Lambda/AWS]

Answer (score 5):

In my case this has happened because my `aws_session_token` got expired and I had to replace all the credentials details:

1. `aws_access_key_id`
2. `aws_secret_access_key`
3. `aws_session_token`

After replacing all the details the error did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your credentials to connect to aws are not present or has expired.
Please try to update your credentials/keys; whatever the way you use to authorise to connect to AWS and then this error should be removed.

This worked for me:
I updated my `~/.aws/credentials` file and it did the magic.